# compare python requests with curl

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am interfacing with an API using `requests` and `requests_oauthlib`.

I successfully authenticate and access all the `GET` methods of the API, but get error 500 with `POST` methods. For example:

```
r = oauth.post("https://api.timelyapp.com/1.0/1/clients", 
data={"client":{"name":"newclient", "color":"c697c0" }}, 
allow_redirects=False, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

The issue is that I tested the same exact call with `curl` and it works correctly, here the `curl` code:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX" --data '{"client": { "name": "newclient", "color":"c697c0" }}' "https://api.timelyapp.com/1.0/1/clients"
```

how can I dig deeper in `requests` to compare its call with `curl`?

UPDATE:

Also, noticed that if I do not specify content type:

```
r = oauth.post("https://api.timelyapp.com/1.0/1/clients", 
data={"client":{"name":"newclient", "color":"c697c0" }}, 
allow_redirects=True)
```

I get instead a 302 with redirection to the site homepage, where I fetch the content of the page. In any case the new client is not added.

Comment: Did you try to change `allow_redirects=False` to True? Many sites do a redirect after a post. You could also run Wireshark on the curl transfer to check if it follows the redirect.

Comment: I still get error 500 also with `allow_redirects=True`

Comment: I would try to use `data=json.dumps(payload)` instead of `data=payload` directly.

Comment: I'd say wireshark is your best friend here... You could also put `requests` in debug mode.

Comment: One difference I see is that curl has an authorization header but your python code doesn't. Have you tried adding that header to the python code?

Comment: @tuananh that was it, thanks!!! can you post it as answer? do you understand why? it is such a simple dictionary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this instead:

```
data=json.dumps(payload)
```

From `python-requests` [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

> There are many times that you want to send data that is not
>   form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data
>   will be posted directly.